# Stacking multiple subfigs around a figure

Tags: subfloats

Im trying to create a figure consisting of three columns. Column 1 and 3 have three subfigs below each other and column 2 has one long thin figure that is the length of page height.

[image]

How is it possible to achieve this?

So far I have:

```latex
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{png}
        \caption{}
        \label{subfig:}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1\textheight]{png}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{png}
        \caption{}
        \label{subfig:}
    \end{subfigure}%
```

Comment: How is the desired vertical alignment of the contents of the first and third column with respect to the second column? Maybe, a sketch of the desired output could be helpful.

Comment: @leandriis i have added a sketch to original post

Comment: Hmmm... I read somewhere someone commenting on not to use `subfigure`, rather use `subfig` instead... ...

Comment: @pushpen.paul: This refers to the usage of the `subfigure` package, that is indeed deprecated. As an alternative, one can use the `subfig` package or the `subcaption` package. (From the code in the question we can conclude that the OP uses the `subcaption` package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice place where to use `\valign`, of course. `;-)`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]

\valign{#\cr
\hbox{\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{First}
  \label{subfig:first}
  \end{subfigure}}
\vfill
\hbox{\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Second}
  \label{subfig:second}
  \end{subfigure}}
\vfill
\hbox{\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Third}
  \label{subfig:third}
  \end{subfigure}}
\cr\noalign{\hfill}
\hbox{\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.15\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Middle}\label{subfig:middle}
  \end{subfigure}}
\cr\noalign{\hfill}
\hbox{\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Fourth}
  \label{subfig:fourth}
  \end{subfigure}}
\vfill
\hbox{\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Fifth}
  \label{subfig:fifth}
  \end{subfigure}}
\vfill
\hbox{\begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Sixth}
  \label{subfig:sixth}
  \end{subfigure}}
\cr
}

\caption{Global caption}\label{fig:global}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `minipage`s and `\vfill`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newlength{\myheight}
\setlength{\myheight}{\textheight}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
      \begin{minipage}[c][\myheight][c]{\linewidth}
        \centering
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{png}
        \caption{}
        \label{subfig:}} 
        \vfill
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{png}
        \caption{}
        \label{subfig:}}
        \vfill
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{png}
        \caption{}
        \label{subfig:}}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=1\textheight, width=\textwidth]{png}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
      \begin{minipage}[c][\myheight][c]{\linewidth}
        \centering
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{png}
        \caption{}
        \label{subfig:}}
        \vfill
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{png}
        \caption{}
        \label{subfig:}}
        \vfill
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{png}
        \caption{}
        \label{subfig:}}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```